# Print String with characters around adding a lot of spaces

Tags: c#, console

Well, I was reviewing C # and tried to make a simple printer. For example, you type a word or phrase and print with = signs around it. But, debugging it, I noticed that when I exceed the character limit, it breaks the style. For example, when I type my name, Gustavo works well:

```
==========         ==========
========== Gustavo ==========
==========         ==========
```

But when I put my full name, it adds a lot of spaces before the name:

```
==========                 ==========
==========      Gustavo Marques ==========
==========                 ==========
```

I would like a suggestion so that I can make the character limit of the upper and lower lines variable or simply find out why the program is printing additional spaces before the word entered O_o. Follow my code below:

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            coolConsolePrint cool = new coolConsolePrint();
            Console.WriteLine("Write down what do you like to print:");
            string thingToWrite = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(cool.printWord(thingToWrite));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class coolConsolePrint
    {
        public string printWord(String word)
        {
            int reps = 0;
            int sets = 0;
            string toPrintString = "";
            int wordSize = word.Length;
            char blank = ' ';
            string style = "==========";
            int styleSize = style.Length;

            while (sets < 3)
            {
                if (reps == 2)
                    toPrintString += style.PadRight(wordSize, blank) + " " + word + " ";
                else
                {
                    if (reps % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        toPrintString += style + "\n".PadLeft(styleSize + wordSize + 2, blank);
                        sets++;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        toPrintString += style.PadRight(styleSize + wordSize + 2, blank);
                    }

                }

                reps++;

            }

            return toPrintString;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a tab (\t) character instead of spaces. 1 tab means 8 spaces, so if string length is 1-8, use 1 tab. If 9-16, use 2 tabs and so on. You can apply a little bit of maths here. Tab will adjust itself regardless of string.

Comment: Well, I've put some verifications after that line: 
toPrintString += style.PadRight(wordSize, blank) + " " + word + " "; //Now this line looks like this:
toPrintString += style; //And after that, is the conditions to add tabs. But the results wasn't as good as expected ^^.
I'll put another comment with how the program prints it.

Comment: Well, in the comments you'll not be able to see it :/. If I answer my question it will be marked as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adjust the width of the output according to how long the word is. This should do the trick.

```
public string printWord(String word) {

  string style = "==========";
  int style_size = style.Length;
  int content_size = word.Length;
  int padding_size = 2; // makes sure that content does not sit right against style
  int line_size = content_size + (style_size * 2) + (padding_size * 2);

  string enclosing_line = 
    style.PadRight(line_size,'=') 
    + Environment.NewLine;

  string content_line = 
    style.PadRight(style_size + padding_size) 
    + word 
    + style.PadLeft((style_size + padding_size)
    + Environment.NewLine;

  return enclosing_line + content_line  + enclosing_line ;

}
```

edited to fix syntax error

Comment: Omg! Difference between pre-junior and senior code! Don't even needed to use a while structure! Very thank you sir!